# Firebase increase badge count with iOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app with Firebase and I implemented push notifications right. And now I'm trying to show badge icon but I can't find a good information to do that. I read I should work on the server side and the example code is something like this.

```
"aps" :  
    {
        "alert" : "Your notification message",
        "badge" : badgecount ,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    }
```

But I don't know where to add the code in my function.

This is how my function looks like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}')
    .onCreate(event => {

        const data = event.data;
        const fromId = data.fromId;
        const toId = data.toId;
        const message = data.message;

        console.log(fromId + ' sent a message to' + toId);

        return admin.database().ref('/users/' + fromId).once('value', snapshot => {

            var user = snapshot.val();

            var payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: user.username,
                    body: message
                }
            }

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.fcmToken, payload)
                .then(function(response) {
                    // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
                    // the contents of response.
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });

            })
```

Can someone give me an advice how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The "apns" object goes in the payload object as a sibling to notification:

```
var payload = {
    notification: {
        title: user.username,
        body: message
    },
    apns: {
    // badge and other ios only data here here
    }
}
```

I would also suggest returning the admin.messaging() method: `return admin.messagins().sendToDevice().ect`. It might not be required, but Firebase suggests returning all thenable references.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out.